# How to make redirection to some vue form from laravel's control?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-router

In my Laravel 5.6 application with vue.js 2.5.7 I and vue-router 3
I use Socialite for login into the system
and in case of success I need to make redirection to some vue form with success message and next options available.

For this I make redirection like:

```
    $url= $site_hosting . "/home";
    return redirect()->route($url, [])->with([
        'text'   => 'google_new_user',
        'type'   => 'success',
        'action' => 'successful_login'
    ]);
```

where url has value like

```
example.com/home
```

the question is that I do not know how redirecting from Laravel control to point to Vue component, defined in resources/assets/js/app.js file as

```
const routes = [
    {
        components: {
            notFound: NotFound,
        ...
```

How can it be done ?

MODIFIED BLOCK # 2
Thank you for the link, but actually I did not catch the decision.
I see in laravel's route file url with "vue_capture"  defintion, 
but in url examples there are

```
/resource/, 
/posts/, 
/posts/{slug}
```

and “storage” in reg expression. What are "storage"/"vue_capture" some predefined names for some actions ?
Could you, please,  give some detailed explanations how it would work, as I need FROM lasravel's action to open vue form?

Also I starting working with vue reading some docs/videos and now my router is defined as :

```
const router = new VueRouter( {
    mode: 'hash', // default
    routes
})
```

with a lot of routes defined.
I mean mode has different value here. Will this example work with this option ?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what you do/don't yet already have in your code. Have you added a route in your `routes/web.php` file to capture VueRouter requests? And do the routes in your `app.js` file have paths?

Comment: I am not sure what have I to add in routes/web.php  and app.js  files... Could you please to give some examples or links to such examples? I hope I explained the problem clearly?

Comment: https://dev.to/mozartted/bullet-proofed-routing-with-laravel-and-vue-part-1-32l could help. Are you basing your code off of any tutorial or template?

Comment: Olease look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2

Answer (score 0):

Check out vue router. https://router.vuejs.org/

Here's an in depth tutorial https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel